# Counting the occurrence of each string in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: dataset, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a data set of movies which has various info on them. One of the columns contains the various genres a movie may belong to like so:

[image]

What I would like to do is count how often a genre occurs in each column, in above example a corresponding series would look like (created the series myself):

[image]

How can I extract this information from the original dataframe using pandas?

Comment: split the columns apart based on `re.split()`

Comment: First make that column a `Categorical` (dtype) then do a `df.groupby().count()`. I'd not heard of `value_counts` but that seems to be an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Equivalent to this should work:

the function(`pandas.Series.str.count`) in this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) will even make it easier...

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex :

```
#using your sample
df[['class1', 'class2', 'class3',..]] = df['genre'].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

Alternative to the above method (but iterating the dataframe)

```
  l = list(df[index-key].values)
  l = (",".join(l))
  l.split('|')
```

And if need remove column `genre` add [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop('genre', axis=1)
```

And then you can use `value_counts()`

But this assumes that you have same length of each `genre` or apply a check first and proceed accordingly..

Or

You can also try using `Counter` from the collections module(after splitting them, just update each key's value)

example [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear'])
Counter({'red': 3, 'apple': 2, 'pear': 1})
```